# Alignment trap , not handling instruction error when trying to build c++ library with arm processor

Tags: c++, build, arm

I'm trying to build the AWS SDK for C++ library on a cubietruck board.
My current software configuration is the following:

```
gcc 4.9.2
cmake 3.8.2
OS: Armbian_5.20_Cubietruck_Debian_jessie_3.4.112
kernel 3.4.112.sun7i
curl : 7.38
aws cpp SDK version :(1.1.46)
```

I tried to build the above c++ library by giving :

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_ONLY="config;core;kinesis"

However the build fails and I receive the following error messages:

**alignment trap: not handling instruction e8de677f at []

Unhandled fault :alignment exception (0x001) at 0x00bb674c

Bus error**

I also tried the following:
1) I tried to build different versions of the library
2) I updated the curl from 7.38 to 7.51
3) I upgraded the os with sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade

But the problem persisted. It seems to be a memory issue either leak or a bad dereferencing but could not find any useful info. 
I checked the in /var/log/syslog but didn't get any new info.
Has anyone come across a similar issue. Since it'a library  what can I do to get more info regarding the problem?